# Pandas sum() TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, typeerror

I have something like this pandas dataframe called **gps**

```
   a  b  label  importe
1  x  y    1     500.2
2  y  z    0     300.4
3  z  x    0     200.3
4  x  z    2     300.6
5  y  y    1     200.7
```

I want to add on an array the sum of the 'importe's with same label, so:

```
print [gps.importe[gps.label == 0].sum(),gps.importe[gps.label == 1].sum(),gps.importe[gps.label == 2].sum()]
```

gives me

```
[500.7, 700.9, 300.6]
```

which I want, but this way:

```
print [gps.importe[gps.label == i].sum() for i in range(3)]
```

gives me

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I actually have more values on the pandas dataframe and more than 3 labels, that's why I need the second option to work.

Why is this error coming up? What am I doing wrong? What would do the trick?

Comment: Both of your codes should work (even though using `groupby` is a more general solution).  Are you absolutely certain that your second code generates the error you say it does (with the input you presented)?

Comment: Works for me.  Which version of Python and Pandas are you using?

Comment: python 2.1.11, pandas 0.17.1

Comment: well, I find my mistake, instead of 3 I had a name of a variable that wasn't an integer, changed that, thanks for telling me it works for you, I noticed it was the only difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is that what you want?

```
In [191]: df.groupby('label').agg({'importe':'sum'})
Out[191]:
       importe
label
0        500.7
1        700.9
2        300.6
```

or:

```
In [192]: df.groupby('label')['importe'].sum()
Out[192]:
label
0    500.7
1    700.9
2    300.6
Name: importe, dtype: float64
```

Comment: it does the job, thanks. I was only looking it one way.